# New tab button on Firefox toolbar?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, default-settings, toolbar

I recently had my Firefox profile corrupted and I had to restore default settings with [this procedure](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).

Previously I had a "new tab" button on my toolbar, and now it doesn't seem to be available anymore. Please note that I'm not talking about the green "plus" icon in the end of the tab bar, I had a "new tab" button on the main toolbar and now I'm used to go there if I want to open a new one.

I use "Tab Mix Plus" but if I'm not mistaking that button was a default Firefox feature, not from this add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want it somewhere on the taskbar next to your bookmarks bar.

Right click on the bar > Customize > Drag the "plus" icon from the top right down to the bar you want it on (Say to the bookmarks bar for example)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I don't think you can add text to this button if that is what you're after?